# Audio gets stuck on stream.write in Pyaudio

Tags: python-3.x, pyaudio, pydub

I am trying to play audio through the play function of pydub `play(audio_segment)` but the function was getting constantly stuck on this function without actually playing the audio.

It seems like **pydub** is getting stuck on the `def _play_with_pyaudio(seg):` in the `stream.open` function of **pyaudio** on the line `stream = Stream(self, *args, **kwargs)`.

If I pause between the creation of **pyaudio** and the opening of the audio stream, it plays through the audio stream just fine.

```
p = pyaudio.PyAudio()
    stream = p.open(format=p.get_format_from_width(seg.sample_width),
                    channels=seg.channels,
                    rate=seg.frame_rate,
                    output=True)
```

I am not getting an error, neither in code or in ALSA debug messages. How do I resolve this, I made sure to reinstall pyaudio, is it a problem in the library or in pyaudio? It seems to me that the problem is somewhere in pyaudio.

I am currently on pyaudio-0.2.11 and pydub 0.23.1. I am working in my personal Lubuntu virtual environment.

Comment: does other audio playback work in the VM? it sort of sounds like the pyaudio isn't able to communicate with the audio device

Comment: @Jiaaro Yes, other audio playback was and is working fine. I actually got this working by calling the function containing the specified pydub function from another python file.